# How to make the popup show up in different languages when I use the custom sign in button?

Tags: javascript, locale, google-signin

I am trying to create a custom google sign in button using the "Building a button with a custom graphic" section @ https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button. The button works perfectly and the integration is also fine. But when I try to extend it to multiple languages the sign in popup always shows up in english and there doesn't seem to be a way to pass the language code to the `auth2.init` as per the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can't

> the Google Sign-In popup language is defined by the language of the user's main Google Account.
>
> ...
>
> What if some of your users' main language is not {the language you chosen}?

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/308#issuecomment-309065449

Comment: Thanks @mosh-feu but the user hasnt signedin yet, that response in that issue is wrong.I want to use the base language the user choose in my website and pass it along.

Comment: I think that it's wrong too, but I'm afraid that this is the answer - it's impossible. P.S. I imagine that if the user hasn't choose a language on Google (not in your site), maybe Google takes they browser's language or by IP or however Google knows the language for non registered user.